# Can I Dispute Non-Received Item Even if I Used PayPal as a Guest

Tags: paypal, shipping

I purchased a Sari on Etsy in September 2020.

Etsy put general note that says "please excuse, there may be delay due to COVID". I used PayPal as a guest (and I got email confirmation of my order)

Every time I asked seller when it will arrive she says, "Ma'am, 5 to 7 days". When I asked for DHL tracking number, seller said she will give tomorrow, but tomorrow never came. Last time I spoke with seller was at Thanksgiving.

When I asked other ladies who bought the same saree, they said that even though seller wasn't responsive, they got item in 2 months. And because the saree was so beautiful they will purchase from seller again even thought it takes too long.

It has been almost 3 months and I haven't received item.

I want to give benefit of the doubt because shipping takes time, but what if something happened to my saree?

I went to PayPay site and they say I can file dispute within 180 days of payment. But what if I purchased as a Guest.

Please advise.

I don't mind the saree coming late (we are in Lockdown after all and it is Winter), but what if it never comes at all?

Comment: Was this purchased with a credit card?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Yes I purchased with Credit Card, through PayPal

Comment: Seems like you should contact PayPal about this, not us.

Comment: @Kat I opened a case in etsy. Hope I can get refund from seller before approaching PayPal. Plz advise further.